# Trying to build tree gives: Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, decision-tree

Running the below code:

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)

Carseats <- Carseats %>% mutate(High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")))

set.seed(2)
train_sample <- sample(nrow(Carseats), 200)
carseats_train <- Carseats[train_sample,]
carseats_test <- Carseats[-train_sample,]

tree.carseats <- tree(High~ . -Sales, Carseats, subset = carseats_train)
```

This will output the error:

```
Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

What is the cause of this and how can I fox it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. My input to tree was incorrect. Namely the `subset` param. This needs to be an expression specifying the subset to be used.

The code can be fixed by using `train_sample` as the input.

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
library(dplyr)

Carseats <- Carseats %>% mutate(High = factor(ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")))

set.seed(2)
train_sample <- sample(nrow(Carseats), 200)
carseats_test <- Carseats[-train_sample,]

tree.carseats <- tree(High~ . -Sales, Carseats, subset = train_sample)
```